# Radius of convergence and convergence sets of $\sum\limits_n\frac{2n+1}{(n-1)^2}x^n$ and $\sum\limits_n(-1)^n(\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n})x^n$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, convergence-divergence

I want to find the radius of convergence of the following series and the set of $x\in \mathbb{R}$ in which the series converge.

1. $$\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{2n+1}{(n-1)^2}x^n$$
2. $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^n(\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n})x^n$$

To find the radius of convergence we have to compute the limit $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\sqrt[n]{|a_n|}$.

Do we do something elese at the first case where the sum starts from $2$ and not from $0$ ?

I have done the following:

1. $$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\sqrt[n]{|a_n|}=\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\sqrt[n]{\left|\frac{2n+1}{(n-1)^2}x^n\right|}=|x|\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\sqrt[n]{\left|\frac{2n+1}{(n-1)^2}\right|}=|x|\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\sqrt[n]{\left|\frac{2n+1}{n^2-2n+1}\right|}=|x|\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\sqrt[n]{\left|\frac{\frac{2}{n}+\frac{1}{n^2}}{1-\frac{2}{n^2}+\frac{1}{n^2}}\right|}$$
2. $$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\sqrt[n]{|a_n|}=\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\sqrt[n]{\left|(-1)^n(\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n})x^n\right|}=|x|\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\sqrt[n]{\left|\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n}\right|}=|x|\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\sqrt[n]{\left|\frac{(\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n})(\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt{n})}{\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt{n}}\right|}=|x|\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\sqrt[n]{\left|\frac{n+1-n}{\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt{n}}\right|}=|x|\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\sqrt[n]{\left|\frac{1}{\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt{n}}\right|}=|x|\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\sqrt[n]{\left|\frac{1}{\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt{n}}\right|}$$

$$$$

Is this correct so far? How could we continue?

Comment: Just a comment: When taking the limit of the $a_n$'s, the $x$ is not included (the $a_n$'s are the coefficients, don't include $x$).

Comment: "To find the radius of convergence we have to compute the limit $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\sqrt[n]{|a_n|}$." No we do not, actually there are other, simpler, approaches that work in tons of cases. The problem you have with all these "radius of convergence of series" questions might be due to the fact that you stay focused on this $\lim\sqrt[n]{|a_n|}$ criterion, that you blindly try to apply, and neglect everything else (including getting an intuitive comprehension of the objects).

Answer (score 4):

You are on the right track.  If one wishes to apply the root test, then the radius of convergence for the first problem is given by

$$\begin{align}
\frac1R&=\lim_{n\to \infty}\sqrt[n]{\frac{2n+1}{(n-1)^2}}\\\\
&=\lim_{n\to \infty}e^{\frac1n \log\left(\frac{2n+1}{(n-1)^2}\right)}\\\\
&=\lim_{n\to \infty}e^{\frac1n (\log(2n+1)-2\log(n-1))}\\\\
&=1
\end{align}$$

Therefore, the radius of convergence, $R$ is $1$

---

The radius of convergence for the second problem is given by

$$\begin{align}
\frac1R&=\lim_{n\to \infty}\sqrt[n]{\left|(-1)^n(\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt n)\right|}\\\\
&=\lim_{n\to \infty}e^{-\frac1n \log\left(\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt{n}\right)}\\\\
&=1
\end{align}$$

Therefore, the radius of convergence, $R$ is $1$

Comment: I got stuck right now... Is the formula for the radius $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\sqrt[n]{|a_n|}$ or $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\sup \sqrt[n]{|a_n|}$ ?

Comment: @marystar The limit superior is equal to the limit when the limit exists.

Answer (score 1):

We can calculate the radius of convergence by the formula too: $R=lim|\frac{a_{n}}{a_{n+1}}|$, where $a_{n}$ is the $n^{\text{th}}$ term of the given series.

In your first problem, $a_n=\frac{2n+1}{(n-1)^2}$ and $a_{n+1}=\frac{2(n+1)+1}{n^2}$. So $\frac{1}{R}=lim\frac{(2n+3)(n-1)^2}{(2n+1)n^2}=lim\frac{(1+\frac{3}{2n})(1-\frac{1}{n})}{(1+\frac{1}{2n})}=1$. Hence Radius of convergence is $1$.

Similarly, we can calculate the second problem.